# Where is operator.idiv in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The function operator.idiv in python2.7 seems to be not present in python 3.4. Is the function gone or where can it be found now?

```
import operator
operator.idiv
>>> AttributeError: module 'operator' has no attribute 'idiv'
```

Comment: Yes, it's gone - the default division in Python 3 is no longer integer, so there's just `ifloordiv` and `itruediv`.

Answer (score 6):

In Python 3, in accordance to [PEP 238](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/), the default division operator `/` was modified to always return a float result, regardless of the input types. So while in Python 2 `3 / 2` and `3.0 / 2` would return different results, you now get a consistent float result in Python 3:

```
>>> 3 / 2
1.5
>>> 3.0 / 2
1.5
>>> 3 / 2.0
1.5
```

The other division operator is the floor division `//` which floors the result (truncates the decimal places). Note that this operator still respects the input types, so using it with two ints will give you an int, while using a float will turn the result into a float too:

```
>>> 3 // 2
1
>>> 3 // 2.0
1.0
>>> 3.0 // 2
1.0
```

So the answer is, yes, the “classic” division operator is gone in Python 3. There is only a “true” division (resulting in a float) and a floor division, accesible using `operator.itruediv` and `operator.ifloordiv` respectively.